# Using Arrayformula to Compare a Range to Variable Entries

Tags: google-sheets

[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y3p9GVTPLP4vNcUDTmG2daChJ3q6jYtBhBaqMI33Eqo/edit#gid=0) is the example sheet. I'm trying to make it so I can put an **age** in `Age!A2:A` and then in `Age!B2:B`, the formula puts in the age range label that's pulled from the sheet `dv`.

Right now, in cell `Age!B1`, is the formula `={"Age Range";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"",QUERY(dv!1:5,"select C where A <= "&A2:A&" and B > "&A2:A&""),""))}`. However, while it'll populate when an age is put in, it only spits out "Child".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a regular vlookup (,... TRUE) type formula.  See the mk.help tab.

```
={"Age Range";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"",VLOOKUP(A2:A,dv!A:C,3),))}
```